# spring-boot test: @get request returns with body null

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, content-negotiation

while doing Content-negotiation testing mock GET returns with null in response body although response status is 200.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Response header 'Content-Type' 
Expected :application/json;charset=UTF-8
Actual   :null
```

here is full test class code. I want to verify that content type is json.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    Controller controller;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/query?mediaType=json"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(header().string(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE));
    }}
```

here is my controller's endpoint.

```
    @RestController
    public class Controller {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/query", produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody ResultSet getResults(
                final HttpServletRequest request
        ) throws Throwable {

       // logic  ...
       SearchService search = (SearchService) context.getBean("search");
       ResultSet result = search.getResults();
       return result;
    }
```

Any thoughts why Body would return as null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your Controller definition in your Test class. As you are testing your `Controller`, you should be using an actual instance of it. Get you `mockMvc` instance for this `Controller` as below (you can do it in your `@Before` annotated setup method):

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new Controller()).build();
```

Comment: for this one, I m getting exception: ``java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set``

Comment: Changed my answer. Please check now.

Comment: Ok, this required me to inject a few mock objects I have in a Controller class but this worked eventually. I noticed that ``@InjectMocks Controller controller`` had same result.